# Laravel Relationships: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I hope someone can please help me here because this is doing my head in.

I have two models, Ingredient and Uom (unit of measure).

In Ingredient I have:

```
public function uom() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Uom::class, 'uom');
}
```

Each ingredient will have only one unit of measure. The column uom in the database is the one that holds the id for the unit of measure.

In Uom I have:

```
public function ingredients() {
    return $this->hasMany(Ingredient::class);
}
```

Each unit of measure could have many ingredients.

In the ingredients table migration I have set up the foreign key as follows:

```
$table->foreign('uom')->references('id')->on('uoms')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Could someone please tell me why in the below foreach I get

```
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object
```

The blade code:

```
@foreach ($ingredients as $ingredient)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$ingredient->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$ingredient->uom->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$ingredient->user->name}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

The $ingredient->user->name works perfectly referencing a column 'added_by' so I'm at a loss as to why uom doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for any help, I hope I'm just overlooking something stupid

Comment: The reason this happens is because you have apparently have an ingredient without any uom associated with it. Maybe that helps a bit. The solution Dilip offers adds a fallback to the relationship.

Comment: I get the fallback and that's awesome. Not something I knew about before. The problem is all my data in the database has integers in the uom column of the ingredients table. So somehow, it's not detecting th foreign key assignment I'm assuming

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. I'll add my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that the attribute has the same name as the relationship method you have: `uom`. If you change the column name on the ingredients from `uom` to `uom_id`, and change the relationship method in the model so the line states the following:

```
public function uom() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Uom::class);
}
```

This should fix your problem (plus the relationship works like Laravel is intended to work)

Laraval has two options: return the relationship (the uom method) or the attribute (which is an integer from the database). Apparently it returns the integer which isn't an object and thus has no method `name`.

Comment: Yes that did it, Thanks!